# Hide of widgets in voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

I'm working in laravel 5.6 with Voyager and I want to implement the widgets of the voyager but however it's showing me all the widgets I have Created but I need to hide some widgets from normal users as some widgets only accessible by Admin.I'm not able to hide the widgets it showing all widgets..
Thanks in advance.

```
public function run()
{

     $count = \App\Organization::count();


    $string = trans_choice('Organization', $count);


    return view('voyager::dimmer', array_merge($this->config, [
        'icon' => 'voyager-edit',
        'title' => [
            'text' => "{$string} {$count}",
            'link' => route('org_data'),
        ],
        // 'image' => voyager_asset('images/widget-backgrounds/03.jpg'),
    ]));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change widget's `shouldBeDisplayed` method as following:

```php
public function shouldBeDisplayed(){
   return auth()->user()->hasRole('admin');
}
```

it simply checks wether current user's role is admin or not.

good luck