# Cannot display Laravel Voyager Widgets in Dashboard

Tags: php, laravel-5, voyager

I am trying to display widgets in my dashboard and it cannot display any widgets.

I follow this video [Voyager Academy Video 15 - Custom Dashboard Widgets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpnjfmaJNPA&t=139s)

I did everything what he did in this video, but cannot display anything in my dashboard.

> config->voyager.php

```
'widgets' => [
        'App\\Widgets\\News',
    ],
```

And I've create a new folder `Widgets` inside app

> app->Widgets->News.php

```
<?php
  namespace App\Widgets;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
  use Illuminate\Support\Str;
  use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;
  use Arrilot\Widgets\AbstractWidget;

  class News extends AbstractWidget
  {

     protected $config = [];

     public function run()
     {
       $count = Voyager::model('Post')->count();
       $string = trans_choice('voyager::dimmer.post', $count);

       return view('voyager::dimmer', array_merge($this->config, [
        'icon'   => 'voyager-news',
        'title'  => "{$count} {$string}",
        'text'   => __('voyager::dimmer.post_text', ['count' => $count, 'string' => Str::lower($string)]),
        'button' => [
            'text' => __('voyager::dimmer.post_link_text'),
            'link' => route('voyager.posts.index'),
        ],
        'image' => voyager_asset('images/widget-backgrounds/02.jpg'),
      ]));
   }

   public function shouldBeDisplayed()
   {
      return Auth::user()->can('browse', Voyager::model('Post'));
   }
 }
```

Ignore inside the run() function, it's just copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

Is cache. 
Just execute - php artisan config:cache

Comment: I install fresh laravel & voyager, and it's working. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem :

```
public function shouldBeDisplayed()
   {
      return Auth::user()->can('browse', Voyager::model('Post'));
   }
```

As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54451571/11387981 [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54451571/11387981) to the same : Change the return fonction.

Answer (score 0):

If you face the same problem and you don't see any changes after you had modified `config/voyager.php` file, try to execute

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to make few changes to :

1. edit the file name and class name from "News.php" to "NewsDimmer.php".
2. change the directory of the file from "app\Widgets" to "vendor\tcg\voyager\src\Widgets\NewsDimmer.php"
3. edit the namespace to "namespace TCG\Voyager\Widgets"
4. change the config/voyager.php :
   'widgets' => [
   'TCG\Voyager\Widgets\NewsDimmer',
   ],

then ,run php artisan config:cache

and it will work , good luck